# TypeError: is_legacy_optimizer is not a valid argument, kwargs should be empty for `optimizer_experimental.Optimizer`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Please help me

Code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model_path = "model/classifier.h5"
model = load_model(model_path)
```

Error:
TypeError: is_legacy_optimizer is not a valid argument, kwargs should be empty  for `optimizer_experimental.Optimizer`.

Comment: Please provide the tensorflow, python version and OS details where you are facing this error to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the model was trained using a different version of tf.

Try confirming if the environment where you trained and are loading have the same tf version.

Comment: Thank you! It helped. I'm usually training my models in Colab, and there tf version (as well as pandas and numpy) can sporadically increase. So working solution was install on inference server exact versions of those libraries which are on colab